# why will this not work, if it worked before? embed message not sending based on role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

code:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 100, type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def tfollow(ctx, channel, amount: int=None):
    print(f'{ctx.author} | {ctx.author.id} -> !tfollow {channel}')
    if ctx.channel.type != discord.ChannelType.private:
        if ctx.channel.id == bots_channel or ctx.author.id in administrators:
            if str(channel.lower()) in tfollow_cooldown and ctx.author.id not in administrators:
                try:
                    await ctx.message.delete()
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                try:
                    if '-' in str(channel):
                        raise Exception
                    max_amount = 0
                    if ctx.author.id in administrators:
                        tfollow.reset_cooldown(ctx)
                        max_amount += 1000
                    premium = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='100 Invites')
                    if premium in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 250
                    diamond = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='75 Invites')
                    if diamond in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 250
                    gold = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='50 Invites')
                    if gold in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 100
                    silver = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='40 Invites')
                    if silver in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 100
                    bronze = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='30 Invites')
                    if bronze in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 100
                    booster = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='20 Invites')
                    if booster in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 50
                    _75 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='15 Invites')
                    if _75 in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 50
                    _25 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='10 Invites')
                    if _25 in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 50
                    _10 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='5 Invites')
                    if _10 in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 50
                    _5 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Booster')
                    if _5 in ctx.author.roles:
                        max_amount += 500
                    max_amount += 50
                    if amount is None:
                        amount = max_amount
                    elif amount > max_amount:
                        amount = max_amount
                    if amount <= max_amount:
                        premium = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Premium')
                        if premium in ctx.author.roles:
                            position = len(queue) + 1
                            # embed = discord.Embed(color=13910757, description=f'Added `tfollow-{channel}-{amount}` to queue! (`1/{position}`)')
                            embed = discord.Embed(color=13910757, description=f'Adding `{amount}` followers to `{channel}`! (`1/{position}`)') 
                            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                            queue.insert(0, f'tfollow-{channel}-{amount}')
                        else:
                            position = len(queue) + 1
                            # embed = discord.Embed(color=13910757, description=f'Added `tfollow-{channel}-{amount}` to queue! (`{position}/{position}`)')
                            embed = discord.Embed(color=13910757, description=f'Adding `{amount}` followers to `{channel}`! (`{position}/{position}`)') 
                            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                            queue.append(f'tfollow-{channel}-{amount}')
                        if ctx.author.id not in administrators:
                            tfollow_cooldown.append(str(channel.lower()))
                            await asyncio.sleep(300)
                            tfollow_cooldown.remove(str(channel.lower()))
                except:
                    embed = discord.Embed(color=13910757, description='An error has occured while attempting to run this command!')
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    tfollow.reset_cooldown(ctx)
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            tfollow.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```

basically what this code is doing is check the roles a person has and adds a number which returns an arg. for some reason now all it returns in discord is the error message, this is copied from my other code which worked fine. i am not sure if it is due to the role names or about the math involved with max_amount and amount

Comment: What's the traceback?

Comment: If you're not getting an error, which we do need to help you better, do replace `except` with `except Exception as e` and do `print(str(e))` after that (or include it in your embed)